# Check if text in data frame exists in any of all headers pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframes from an excel called

df1, df2, df3, df4

I also have df called df5 below.

```
  A        B          C
df1       df2         df3
df1       df3         df4
```

How do I check if A, B, C each row contains text, then get that named df and do action.  All dataframes are labeled A, B, C

So for row 1,

```
go to df1 df1.pop('A')
go to df2 df2.pop('A')
go to df3 df3.pop('A')
```

I'm aware of solutions that involve columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], columns=['A', 'B'])
aa = ((df['A'] == 2) & (df['B'] == 3)).any()
```

Not quite what I desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below could be one way to handle this.

create a dictionary mapping dataframe names to data frame objects

```
objs={'df1': df1 , 'df2':df2, 'df3' : df3}
```

define a function which manipulate the dataframes

```
def handler(df):
    df.pop('A')
```

Then apply for the df columns as

```
df['A'].apply(lambda x : handler(objs.get(x)))
```

may be not the most elegant way, but should meet your requirement.